# Fetching values from JSON - Clojure

Tags: json, clojure

How can I get the value of id in Clojure? I am using clj-json.

```
{
"response": {
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "state": 0
        }
    ]

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the input JSON is in a string variable named `input`:

```
(require '(clj-json [core :as json]))
(-> (json/parse-string input) (get-in ["response" "users"]) first (get "id"))

=> "5"
```

Comment: if the value under `"users"` is a `vector` you can also do `(get-in json ["response" "users" 0 "id"])`